# React Native FlatList nested inside FlatList with same orientation

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-flatlist, react-native-scrollview

I Cant create FlatList nested inside FlatList with same orientation;

the result is that the parent is horizontal but the children are vertical;

this is my code:

```js
renderSlides(question) {
    return <View key={question.item.code}
                 style={{flex: 1,width:350}}>
        <FlatList
            ref='scrollPick'
            data={[{k:'A'},{k:'b'},{k:'c'}}]}
            horizontal={true}
            renderItem={(rate)=>{return (
                <View >
                    <Text>{rate.item.k}</Text>
                </View>);}}
            keyExtractor={ (item, index) => index}
        />
    </View>;
}

render() {
    return (
        <View style={CONTAINERS.MAIN_COLUMN_BLUE}>
            <View style={[NAV.CONTAINER_GENERAL, NAV.CONTAINER_ASSESSMENT, {flex: 1}]}>
                <TopBar barType="ex" title={I18n.t('assessment.title')} navigator={this.props.navigator}
                        closeFunction={this.handleClose}></TopBar>
            </View>
            <FlatList
                ref={(ref) => { this.flatListRef = ref; }}
                horizontal={true}
                data={[{k:'1'},{k:'2'},{k:'3'},{k:'4'},{k:'5'},{k:'6'},{k:'q'}]}
                renderItem={this.renderSlides}
                keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}
                horizontal={true}
                getItemLayout={this.getItemLayout}
                contentContainerStyle={{ flexGrow: 1}}
            />
        </View>
    );
}
```

[image]

Has anyone run into this same problem?
**( And I can't use scrollView )**

Comment: have you tried to use `flexDirection : 'row'` on <View> tag like __<View style={{flexDirection : 'row'}}> </View>__

Comment: its dosent work

Comment: @AharonVishinsky Did you find the solution?

Comment: Solution found yet?

Answer (score 9):

Finally I have found it!

The First FlatList you import from `react-native`

```
import {FlatList} from 'react-native'
```

And the second (inside-FlatList) you can import from `react-native-gesture-handler`

```
import {FlatList as FlatList2} from 'react-native-gesture-handler'
```

Then you can use the same orientation and it will work.

Comment: You saved me...I have been looking for a solution for more than 3 days.

Comment: it worked on ios like a charm, But doesn't seems to work on android  :-(

Comment: This works for me too, but any reason why this is working?